# Create wrapper function with extra parameters

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a function that accepts another function and returns 3rd function with extra parameters and ensures type safety.

```
function createWrapper<TFunc>(TFunc func) {
    return (innerParams: Parameters<TFunc>, extraParam1: number, extraParam2: string) => {
       const innerResult = func(innerParams);
       return modifyInnerResultWithExtraParams(innerResult, extraParam1, extraParam2);
    }
}
```

Is it possible?